# Can a liquid turn to a solid by applying pressure?

Tags: phase, pressure

When pressure increases, volume decreases. If an extremely high pressure is applied to a liquid, is it possible to reduce it's volume to an extent where the molecules are very tight together, hence becoming a solid? Or do changes in pressure and volume not alter the physical properties of the substance and the liquid remains liquid?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It *is* possible to change a liquid into a solid, or in general change the phase a substance finds itself in by just altering the pressure.

You might want to refer to some graphs known as *Phase diagrams* that portray the effect of temperature and pressure on the physical state of a substance.

[image: phase diagram]
<sub>(source: [purdue.edu](http://chemed.chem.purdue.edu/genchem/topicreview/bp/ch14/graphics/14_14fig.gif))</sub>

In this example if you're to draw a straight line from the point B to D, it'll have a subtle positive slope. So there's a possibility to transform a liquid into a solid without making any changes to the temperature conditions.

You might have heard of solid $\ce{CO2}$ or dry ice. I might be wrong but a part of me says carbon dioxide is *pressurised* and refrigerated for it to form.

An interesting thing to note here is that in case of a gas turning into a liquid, there's a temperature known as *Critical Temperature* ($T_c$) above which the gas cannot be liquified no matter how much pressure is applied.

Comment: Since the curve from B to D is concave, following the straight line from B to D will never leave the liquid phase. But if you choose a temperature between B and D and change the pressure (i.e. follow a line parallel to the pressure axis), you will see a phase transition (liquid/solid).

Comment: Actually, the phase diagram for water seems to go the other way.

Comment: @ChesterMiller Agreed. Phase diagram of water is different from those of other compounds.

Comment: It's only *locally* different; about 1 GPa would solidify it all right.